# A question from 2009 just showed up in the Low Quality review queue

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts

So I was going along my merry way in the LQ review queue, and lo and behold [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696720/jquery-validation-plugin-selected-control) shows up.

The question is definitely low quality, I'm not arguing that. I clicked "recommend close". But then I noticed that the question was posted in 2009.

So, that's weird. Why is such an old post showing up in the queue? Here's the link to the [review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3226904).

Comment: That's definitely weird. I just voted to close also, it looked like an audit at first with the grayed out username. Maybe someone flagged it? That sounds like a probable reason as to why it was added.

Comment: There are probably thousands of questions from 2009 that should be in the queue but aren't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A user had flagged the post as "very low quality" - which after being active for 15 minutes bumped it into the Low Quality Posts queue. Nothing weird here.

Comment: The interesting thing about this situation was that the review task sync happened *while the flag was being created* - resulting in the review task being dated *slightly* before the flag. Nothing incorrect resulted from this, but it did throw me for a bit when viewing the timeline.