# Recommend deletion of old answer

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

I encountered something like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203219/a-question-from-2009-just-showed-up-in-the-low-quality-review-queue/203222#203222) with [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/239590) review item. I would now like to recommend deletion, because it might be speculation, but it's more likely a "me too" comment. However, I only get the options "no comment needed" and "link-only answer".

Why is that the case?

For now I've just written an explanation in a comment and flagged it as "no comment needed", hoping that other people see my comment.

Comment: You should ask this on Gaming Meta.

Comment: No, it's a problem that could appear on all sites.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this was flagged as NAA since we can no longer flag old answers as VLQ. (the answer you found here is outdated). So I'm pretty sure the available comments are based on the type of flag that was cast. Still not 100% sure about all this, hence only comment and not an answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The options are in no way dependant on the type of flag cast.  A NAA flag *is appropriate* for that post, because it's not actually an answer. It's by far the superior flag to using VLQ, given that the post isn't actually an answer.

Comment: For other readers: NAA means "not an answer" and VLQ means "very low quality". Took me some time to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other comment options are hidden because the answer is older than 6 months.

The idea is that should not leave a comment on those posts and just silently recommend to delete them, since OP probably won't react to your input after all that time.

To quote [Shog9 from here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318484/559745):

> Truth is, once you get more than a month out, the chance of anything useful happening in response to any of the canned review comments is pretty low. They become little more than noise, the sorts of meta commentary you usually see junking up traditional forums. And Stack Overflow is supposed to be a place without all that "forum noise".

> On answers 6 months old or older, the "link only" comment will be the only one available in review.

Comment: Hm, ok. I don't agree with it, but I can accept it as the answer.